# Python SQL query returns some values as None when present in the DB

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a query which looks like:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = '%s'" % (userID)
cursor.execute(sql)
rowCount = cursor.rowcount
result = cursor.fetchone()

print(result)
```

after few good queries response will return result which looks like:

```
(1584, None, None, '1316911449', 'Erik', 'C', 'Tester', '', 'V', '0', '', datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 4, 2, 13, 14), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 4, 2, 13, 13), datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 4, 2, 13, 14))
```

when the DB contains values for second and third column as hashes

```
1584    0dcfa75b5ed837cb9446891022eb6465    0dcfa75b5ed837cb9446891022eb6465    1316911449  Erik    C   Tester      V   0       2019-12-04 14:03:40 2019-12-04 02:13:13 2019-12-04 14:03:40
```

Any clue why those values are getting dropped on a select query after few good rounds?

PS.
It looks like it is always got dropped after the row #1585 from the DB.

Comment: This is hard to believe. On another note: if `userId` is being entered from the outside, you are open to a SQL Injection attack. Better would be: `sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE userID = %s"` and then: `cursor.execute(sql, (userId,))`. This is better in any case -- what if `userId` had a `'` character in it?

Comment: OK, I will update SQL statement but yes - hard to believe but after good run I have `None` data returned :(

Comment: @Booboo It looks like after the row #1585 it starting to drop those values from `result`